# How to insert an auto-generated id into another table in jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

Can you please help me, I need to insert an auto-generated key, ADDRESS_ID, into another table, DEBTOR, where it is a foreign key? Below is part of my code?

```
try {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/CreditManager";
        String uName = "fact";
        String uPass = "r107866x";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        String query1 = "insert into ADDRESS (ADDRESS_LINE1, ADDRESS_LINE2, PROVINCE)"
                + "values (?,?,?)";
        String query = "insert into DEBTOR (NATIONAL_ID, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME,       SURNAME,PHONE_NUMBER,DOB)"
                + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
        preparedStatement1.setString(1, address_line1);
        preparedStatement1.setString(2, address_line2);
        preparedStatement1.setString(3, province);
        preparedStatement1.executeUpdate();

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, national_id);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, fname);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, mname);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, sname);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, phone_no);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, dob);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


        // execute insert SQL stetement

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddAccountForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29

Comment: http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-retrieve-automatically-generated-keys-in-jdbc/173. Google is your friend.